# Access different nodes of same name

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a situation where I have an xml file that has different levels of child nodes called the same thing. An example here would be:

```
<listing>
<post_town>London</post_town>
<price>940000</price>
<longitude> 51.2</longitude>
<latitude>20.000</latitude>
<price_change>
    <date>2020-01-30 08:43:36</date>
    <direction/>
    <percent>0%</percent>
    <price>975000</price>
</price_change>
<price_change>
    <date>2020-02-20 15:59:01</date>
    <direction>down</direction>
    <percent>-3.5%</percent>
    <price>940000</price>
</price_change>
<price_change_summary>
<direction>down</direction>
<percent>-3.5%</percent>
</listing>
```

I have a script run that doesn't seems to work, I want it to ignore the "price" child nodes in the  elements of the xml. This script looks as follows:"

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://test.co.uk/xmltest.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
var x, y, z, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
txt = "";
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("latitude");
y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("longitude");
z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price");


for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    txt += "{location:" + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", " + y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +", weight:" + z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "},<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As an example from the above it should be "{location: 51.2, 20.000, weight:940000},
" - ignoring the  items in the  element and looping for many different listings to pull out the same info as above.

The ultimate aim is to sift through this xml and print out the latitude, longitude and original price for each listing and I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML provided is malformed. `<price_change_summary>` has no closing tag. So it is not valid XML. Once you place closing tags on that element it will work correctly.

EDIT after comments:

Change your selectors for `y` and `z` so that you are selecting the siblings of each `x`. Do this in the loop thus:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   const long = x[i].parentNode.querySelector('longitude');
   const price = x[i].parentNode.querySelector('price');
        txt += "{location:" + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", " + long.childNodes[0].nodeValue +", weight:" + price.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "},<br>";
    }
```

Comment: This was an error on my part adjusting the XML as an example. What happens when fully formed is that all prices show up and are mismatched with the listing long/lat

Comment: I guess I didn't glean that from your question. This is most likely due to the fact that you are dealing with live NodeLists here and order is not guaranteed. I realize you are trying to be efficient, but this is an odd way to perform a loop over a structured document.

Comment: Hmmm... short of manually pulling out <price_change> prices, is there any way to do this efficiently?  Sorry, I am new to this, so the method might not be best practice

Comment: Thanks @randy  - this looks to have solved my question

Comment: here is the correct XML https://xmleditoronline.org/?id=cc227192fb1ed46f774684b94a010046-YGxcBy